# Using variables to build dynamic MongoDB/Mongoose query of nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, template-literals

My app has 4 identical Node/Express API routes that are meant to remove an nested object property within a MongoDB database.  The only difference in syntax between these 4 routes is a string value (either "facebook", "google", "twitter" or "github".  Here is one of the four routes:

```
  app.get("/unlink/facebook", async (req, res) => {
    await User.update(
      { _id: req.user._id },
      {
        $unset: {
          "authProviders.facebook.facebookId": "",
          "authProviders.facebook.facebookDisplayName": "",
          "authProviders.facebook.facebookEmail": ""
        }
      }
    );
    res.redirect("/preferences");
  });
```

My aim is to refactor these four routes into a single endpoint by adding a parameter onto the Express route's URL that would become a string variable representing one of the four social media account types. The point of the route would be to dynamically determine which social media account property to **$unset** (delete) within the **authProviders** object in the MongoDB **User** document.

I attempted to build the MongoDB query to access the necessary object property using ES6 template literals, however I receive an error: **"SyntaxError: Unexpected template string"**.

Below is the code for my attempt at refactoring to a singular endpoint using ES6 template literals and the social media variable:

```
app.get("/unlink/:account", async (req, res) => {
      let accountType = req.params.account;
      let email = accountType + "Email";
      let id = accountType + "id";
      let displayName = accountType + "DisplayName";
    await User.update(
      { _id: req.user._id },
      {
        $unset: {
          `authProviders[${accountType}][${id}]`: "",
          `authProviders[${accountType}][${email}]`: "",
          `authProviders[${accountType}][${displayName}]` : ""
        }
      }
    );
    res.redirect("/preferences");
  });
```

Here is the MongoDB document:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make this work?? I can't seem to figure out how to structure the MongoDB query to access the object property using variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to make this happen.  Posting resolution just in case another nascent developer runs into this.

```
app.get("/unlink/:account", async (req, res) => {
    let accountType = req.params.account,
        query1 = "authProviders." + accountType + "." + accountType + "Id",
        query2 = "authProviders." + accountType + "." + accountType + "Email",
        query3 = "authProviders." + accountType + "." + accountType + "DisplayName";
    await User.update(
      { _id: req.user._id },
      {
        $unset: {
          [query1]: "",
          [query2]: "",
          [query3]: ""
        }
      }
    );
    res.redirect("/preferences");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this :

```
app.get("/unlink/:account", async (req, res) => {
      let accountType = req.params.account;
    await User.update(
      { _id: req.user._id },
      {
        $unset: {
          authProviders[`${accountType}.${accountType}id`]: "",
          authProviders[`${accountType}.${accountType}email`]: "",
          authProviders[`${accountType}.${accountType}displayName`] : ""
        }
      }
    );
    res.redirect("/preferences");
  });
```

Comment: It seems that the $unset object properties are expected to be strings (in quotes).  Using the code that you provided results in an "SyntaxError: Unexpected token [   " error in Node.  That is the initial reason that I began experimenting with template literals.